# DataGridView item double click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in a Windows Form. I want to handle double click events on each cell to display a detail form related to that record. Unfortunately, the double click event is executed when you double click on column headers. What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should check the `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` property of the event arguments. If one of them is negative, it means that either a row header or a column header is clicked, you should ignore that event.

Answer (score 5):

What event are you handling? Ideally you should handle the `CellDoubleClick` or the `CellMouseDoubleClick` events and opening your details form in that handler. The latter event will catch a Double click using any of the mouse buttons (the button can be queried using the `MouseEventArgs.Button` property.

Comment: This doesn't solve the specific problem the OP mentioned at all: "Unfortunately, the double click event is executed when you double click on column headers"